# Python3 RSA publickKey encryption

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I got a public key to work with and I need to cipher some text with the public RSA key I got.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import rsa

fKey = open('key','r')
publicKey = fKey.read()

cipher = rsa.encrypt('Test', publicKey)
print(cipher)
```

With this code I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 30, in <module>
    cipher = rsa.encrypt('Test', publicKey)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 169, in encrypt
    keylength = common.byte_size(pub_key.n)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Note: I must use that public key file**

Comment: What package exactly are you using there…?

Comment: "'str' object has no attribute 'n'" - it looks like it's expecting you to unpack the public key from the format that it's in (X509 PEM?) into the modulus and exponent values. Your library doesn't just accept the raw file contents.

Comment: Look at the documentation how to load keys: https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#usage. The function expects an instance of `PublicKey`, not a string read straight from a file: https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#functions

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode,b64encode

pubkey = open('key','r').read()
msg = "Test"
keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode())
emsg = b64encode(cipher_text)
print(emsg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
fKey = open('key','rb')
publicKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(fKey.read())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).